# Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'Memory' requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, c#-7.2

I have the below snippet of code to test/use dotnet 2.1 in vs 2017 in order to try out and run C# 7.2s Span functionality.
Where can I find the SDK that allows me to run this within Visual Studio.
I can only find frameworks up to 2.0.

```
using System;
using System.Memory;

namespace sim
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       var arr = new byte[10];
        Span<byte> bytes = arr; // Implicit cast from T[] to Span<T>

        Span<byte> slicedBytes = bytes.Slice(start: 5, length: 2);

    }      
}
}
```

Otherwise I'm left unable to run and use 
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'Memory' requires 1 type arguments    sim

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 is still in preview: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md

Comment: But there's the VS2017 preview which presumably works with the 2.1 preview: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: Why does this question have the title it does?  It seems to have nothing to do with that error.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install any SDK for using `Span<T>`

You need to install `System.Memory` nuget package which is prerelase version.

you can use this command

```
Install-Package System.Memory -Version 4.5.0-preview2-26406-04
```

You also need to set your language version to `7.2` in your project properties and also you need Visual Studio 15.5 or more

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? [.NET Core SDK 2.1.4](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.4)

Comment: I have this installed already, it will does not create a .Net Core 2.1 option in the TargetFramework section of the project menu