# Use Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core SDK 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-3.0

How Can I open `.Net Core 3.0` project in Visual Studio 2017?

I have downloaded the .NET Core 3.0 SDK from [dotnet.microsoft.com](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) and created new project with `dotnet new` command in a folder.

Building C# project shows error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either
>   target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that
>   supports .NET Core 3.0.

I checked it but it doesn't work in my case:

[Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core SDK 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618678/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-2-0)

[Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core SDK 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916183/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-2-1)

Comment: 2019 Preview 5 has an installer.. 2.1 appears to be the highest version that installs into 2017, although 2.2 tools are also available.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

.In VS 2017: You can just go to the *Tools* → *Options* → *Project and Solutions* → *.NET Core* and  then check *Use previews of the .NET Core SDK*

Comment: This is also true for VS2019 RC, however I did have to restart VS in order for the change to take effect

Comment: This seems to be no longer true with .net core 3.0 Preview 3.

Comment: VS2019 release requires this settings change as well. Works with .net core 3.0 preview 3. Ensure to restart.

Answer (score 48):

Unfortunately .NET Core 3 requires MSBuild 16. Even if you enable preview versions of .NET Core in VS 2017 as others have suggested you will still get the error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0. Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0.

If you create a `global.json` file and put in eg.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.100-preview5-011568"
  }
}
```

You then get shown the real problem which is:

> error : Version 3.0.100-preview5-011568 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.0.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.`

MSBuild 16 only comes with VS 2019, so, the answer is that you CAN use VS 2017 with .NET Core 3, but only if you also have VS 2019 installed as well!

Comment: Can'y you just install MSBuild 16 separately?

Comment: @JanneHarju I tried to install the Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 but it didn't seem to help, only the full Visual Studio 2019 did. Worth trying again though I had various other issues.

Comment: @user917170 Does this means I have to buy Visual Studio 2019 now? Or is there some other way? Also do you think they will also make this available for 2017?

Comment: @Morganis I didn't look into it any further so not sure if there is a workaround, but you could probably just install the free Visual Studio 2019 Community edition and not have to pay anything except bandwith and hard drive space, then keep using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: How do you target MSBuild 16?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Not sure what you mean, .NET Core 3 always targets MS build 16

Comment: @user917170 exactly. But VS2017 uses msbuild 15.x and I cannot find a way how to "tell" VS to use a different msbuild file.

Answer (score 8):

### Visual Studio 2019 update

About the original answer from @GoDev :

> Starting with Visual Studio 2019, the option has moved to:
>
> Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features

[image: Option screen]

[Official notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/)

Answer (score 4):

`.Net Core 3.0` requires Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1, you can't use Visual Studio 2017. According to the [**.Net Blog**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/), "Visual Studio 2019 will be the release to support building .NET Core 3 applications" and requires .Net 4.8

When creating a new application/project, the project declares a dependency on .Net Core 3.0 via the netcorepp3.0 target framework.

Comment: It is possible, it's just an unsupported scenario. From the blog you linked: *"It is currently possible to open .NET Core 3.0 projects in Visual Studio 2017 15.9, however, it is not a supported scenario (and you need to [enable previews](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/13/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/))."*

Comment: True, but it stands, `it is not a supported scenario`, just because you can doesn't mean you should. Then the case where things start happening and you don't know why... Thanks for your input @Stijn!

Comment: I do agree with "just because you can doesn't mean you should" :) better to just use the 2019 preview instead.

Answer (score 4):

Came across the same issue and [this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/current-net-sdk-not-support-net-core-3-0-fix/) article helped to sort out

## 1. Check if .NET Core SDK 3.x is installed

[image]

If there is none, go to the official .NET Core 3 Download page and get it, then install it and try again.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

## 2. Enable .NET Core  SDKs Previews

[image]

.NET Core 3.0 preview1 was the last version of .NET Core 3.0 that worked with Visual Studio 15.9 (aka Visual Studio 2017): any subsequent release of .NET Core 3.0 (including nightlies) require VS 16.0+, aka Visual Studio 2019.

## 3. Check the PATH environment variables

[image]

Reference : https://www.ryadel.com/en/current-net-sdk-not-support-net-core-3-0-fix/

Answer (score 3):

To create or open applications targeting .NET Core 3.0, Visual Studio 2019 or newer is required.
When creating a new project Visual Studio may show you a yellow bar with the message "ASP.NET Core 3.0 or newer projects are not supported by this version of Visual Studio"

more informaion:
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/dotnet-core-3.0-preview1.md

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable "**Use previews of the .NET Core SDK**" from

> Visual Studio's tools | Options | Project and Solutions | .NET Core

---

After this, you need to restart visual studio and you will be able to use ".NET Core 3" projects.

You can also follow [youtube page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIlfHtqgKk8&list=PLG8rj6Rr0BU8GIaI9YfU3yuEcHc9Fsq_0&index=3) for any further queries regarding ".NET Core 3".

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in latest vs preview. Install it following steps in here. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/install-preview?view=vsmac-2019

Answer (score 0):

If you're here from the future and there's no specific reason to stay on 2017, upgrading to 2019 will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

install .net core 2.0. visual studio 2017 for .net core works for version 2.0, 1.1 and 1.0

Comment: This is an old question and your post doesn't answer the question, which has already been flagged as solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31393983)