# .Net Core unable to detect Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am facing below issue in .Net Core. I have added **Microsoft.VisualBasic** nuget package to .Net Core class library but still getting issue.

> The type or namespace name 'FileIO' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I didn't get above issue in .Net framework.

How to resolve above issue

Comment: Related topic : Visual Basic’s File IO Added to .NET Core
https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/02/VB-File-IO-Core/

Comment: As per given article, File IO supported in .Net Core 3.0 .Looks like .Net Core 3.0 is supported in VS 2019. How can I use .Net Core 3 in VS Enterprise 2017.

Comment: .Net Core 3 is in preview, RC planned in July, GA in September. How to use in VS2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641740/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-3-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698869/microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO on .Net Core currently.

Maybe you can use some library like this, it would achieve the same results: https://github.com/bimonsubio1984/CommonCore/tree/master/Ported.VisualBasic

Answer (score 0):

with the FileIO functionality there is the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2). This is an RFC compliant CSV parser that can also handle fixed-width files.