# Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO reference

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1, textfieldparser

I want to use `TextFieldParser` in my project. For that I need `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO`.

However Visual Studio accepts `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` without the `FileIO`. but it does not recognize the TextFieldParser class.
On other forums, I read I should add *Microsoft.VisualBasic* reference. I am not able to work out how to do this, since the window of *Reference Manager* is completely blank, so I do not have any option to chose from.

[image: Image of window]

Any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12830017/1070452

Comment: No, none of these is answer to my question.

I cannot add reference, since I do not have any possibilities to choose from.

Comment: If you're targeting .net core 3, you shouldn't have an issue. Previous versions you may need to look into a library like CsvHelper instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Add Reference" dialog that you have read about adds .NET Framework references, but you are targeting .NET Core. In .NET Core, either what you need is built in to the framework or you reference a Nuget package or class library to get the extra features you need. Adding a reference to another 'part' of the framework - like `Microsoft.VisualBasic` - isn't a thing in .NET Core.

With regards to `TextFieldParser`, the bad news is that it is not available in .NET Core 2.1, as is made clear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.1).

However, we can see from the documentation and the [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser) that the class *is* available in .NET Core 3.0. Therefore you have 2 choices:

- Upgrade to .NET Core 3.0, or
- Make do without this class and use a different approach

Comment: Yes, thank you. Eventually I did it in different way.

Comment: There is a NuGet package named CsvTextFieldParser that looks like it may be useful for pre-.NET Core 3.0 projects.