# Visual Studio Code .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a Dot Net Core 3.0 project in Visual Studio Code Version 1.39.2. When I do `dontnet run` I am getting the error:

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower,or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Do you have the .NET Core 3.0 SDK installed?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Windows, MacOs, etc?

Comment: error is bit more informative, worried about: Is it VS Code or Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm on Windows. I think I am missing the SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641740/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-3-0)

Comment: @John Installed the SDK and the issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Also helps if you run `dotnet run`...