# Why is .Net core 3.1 not available as target framework in Visual Studio Community Edition 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-3.1

This is my first project on .net and Visual Studio. This may be a really basic question. However, I looked through the questions, web and documentation but could not find the answer.

I have Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 15.9.21 and dotnet 3.1 sdk is installed.

```
      .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.102
 Commit:    573d158fea

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18363
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.2
  Commit:  916b5cba26

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.512 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

But when I choose new project and get to .net framework, only option I see is .Net 2.1.

How do I configure to see 3.1 .net?

[image: Visual Studio showing only 2.1]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641740/

Comment: Why are you using VS 2017? VS 2019 is out. And since you're on community, it's free for you.

Comment: I already applied the solution mentioned in that question. Problem still exists

Comment: This was the first one that popped up on visual studio website for download. I clicked on check for updates and it said there are no updates available. I will look for VS 2019 specifically

Comment: Check for Updates only looks for updates to VS 2017. VS 2019 is a completely separate install.

Comment: Thanks, and my mistake. When I searched for Visual Studio on my windows, it launched Visual Studio Installer and the only options in that were for VS 2017. Downloading VS 2019 now.

Comment: I downloaded VS2019 and now I can see both .net core (2.1 and 3.1). Thanks
@mason, please post an answer i.e. VS 2017 does not support 3.1, we need to install VS 2019 so that I can accept that answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately .NET Core 3 requires MSBuild 16 which only comes with VS 2019.

Comment: I have visual studio 2019 still. Still, it's 3.1 is not showing up as part of the target framework.