# Problem of loading new .NET CORE into Visual Studio 2017 c# .NET CORE project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have installed both .NET CORE 3.1. and preview 5.0. I see it when I type command:
dotnet --list-sdks
I see all packages

[image]

but when I want to use it in VS project in C# .NET CORE console app I cannot.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Core SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641740/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried .NET CORE 3.x with VS 2017 but according this [page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) it is possible that is is supported only in VS 2019.

You might also try to restart Visual Studio. I think it loads installed frameworks only during startup.

Also check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641740/use-visual-studio-2017-with-net-core-sdk-3-0). You might find there some answers